# SQL All rows in one table next to all rows from second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table1:
a
b
c

Table2:
d
e
f
```

How do I obtain the following results in sql server:=?

```
ad
ae
af
bd
be
bf
cd
ce
cf
```

These tables have no columns in common. I just want to see all possible combinations of all the rows in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2
```

Comment: Follow up question, what is wrong with this: SELECT a, b
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2
where (a, b) not exists

(select a, c from Table1
join Table3 on d = e) It is giving me an error.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do without more info. Your syntax is incorrect. `where (a,b) not exists (....)` doesn't make sense

Comment: If you want exact answers than,                                                            select col1+col2 from #table1
cross join #table2
order by col1

Answer (score 1):

CROSS JOIN is what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query to get required output:

```
select * from Table1, Table2
```